# Broadcast receiver stop triggering when swipe clear the app

Tags: android, android-studio, broadcastreceiver

**Broadcast receiver** stop triggering "onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)" method after  clear(swipe) app from recent list , how to solve this issue ?

Manifest code

```
   <receiver
    android:name="*.receiver.TestReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />

        <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
        <category android:name="pacakge" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Receiver Code

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    LogUtils.LOGD("notfy",  "Receiver : ");
    if(intent!=null){
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if(extras!=null) {
            try {
                String regId = extras.getString("registration_id");
                String message = extras.getString("message");
                String qsid = extras.getString("id","");
                String type = extras.getString("type","");
                // extras.getString("aps");


                       /*code*/



            } catch (Exception e){

                LogUtils.LOGD("notfy",  "onReceive last exception: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: push notifications ?

Comment: You have to reschedule your jobs https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html

Comment: @Jithish Can you tell me more about your requirement?

Comment: Not get push notifications after clear app from recent list.

Comment: U need to do register the receiver in a service in order to do as intended

Comment: but broadreceiver not triggers onReceive method. @Avinash Roy any tutorial for that ?

Comment: show me the part of the code of ur receiver

Comment: @Avinash Roy added code.. even onReceive method not triggering .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In main app start/stop the service

```
Intent service = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
context.startService(service);
...
Intent service = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
context.stopService(service);
```

service

```
  public class MyService extends Service
    {
     private static BroadcastReceiver m_Receiver;

     @Override
     public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0)
     {
      return null;
     }
    @Override
  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return START_STICKY;
    }

     @Override
     public void onCreate()
     {
      Receiver();
     }

     @Override
     public void onDestroy()
     {
     unregisterReceiver(m_Receiver);
     }

     private void Receiver()
     {
     m_Receiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
      {
       @Override
       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
       {
        //place all ur stuff here
       }
      }

     }
    }
```

Comment: main app means Custom Application class ?  so manifest receiver register code need to remove or not ? where will i put stop service ?

Comment: dont remove anything from manifest,They are system broadcasts,and yes u need to start service in ur main activity

Comment: where will put stop service ?

Comment: check the edit,make the service sticky and u can destroy service in onDestroy() callback,the system will switch on the service back when memory is available

Comment: This way ur service will be ON most of the time irrespective of whether ur app is killed or alive

Comment: so any of the activty  put startservice , stopservice  , will work all time ? irrespective of app, activity live or not.

Comment: only if the service is sticky

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157283/discussion-between-jithish-p-n-and-avinash-roy).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is on the server side ,

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options

There are two types of messages

> With FCM, you can send two types of messages to clients:
>
> Notification messages, sometimes thought of as "display messages."
>   Data messages, which are handled by the client app.

Basically change from notification to data on your server , this will call OnRecieve when app is closed.

Check the link for more info and examples

Comment: it works fine app background, app exit , lock screen states. problem is   1)mostly triggering . sometimes not..  2)after clear app recent list it stops triggering.

Comment: the server is sending data or notification